# Issue with spring-beans.dtd file

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am getting this error in my spring-hibernate.xml file

Referenced file contains errors (http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd)

seems like some jar file is missing or not using correct version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `spring-beans-{version}.jar` on your classpath?